# How must a function pointer be defined, which points to a function with variadic arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers, variadic, platformio

The goal is to have logging, both under Arduino / espressif platform and native. C++ 11 is used.

For example:

```
logx("Text val1: %d, val2: %u", a, 123);
------> 20:24:27.237 > [    26][D][main-log3.cpp:60] setup(): Text val1: 2, val2: 123
```

The PlatformIO supports Unit Tests (UT). The UT are executed in the so-called native mode, i.e. here is
no Arduino framework available, which makes sense. Thus the Arduino / espressif logging does not work.
However, the following approach should enable logging both in the case of a deployement and in the case of UT.
There are two logging functions, one for native mode and one for deployment, in different files of course.
The log functionality is defined with the following macro:

```
#define logx(format, ...) logStruct.loggerCb(ARDUHAL_LOG_FORMAT(X, format), ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

There is a structure with a function pointer, which points to one of the two logging functions (nativeLogger, arduinoLogger)
refers.

```
template <typename... Args>
using logging_t = void(const char *, Args &&...args);

template <typename... Args>
struct LogStruct_t {
    logging_t<Args> *loggerCb;
};
```

The plan is, either in a macro (preferred) or in the setup routine, to place the appropriate logging function at the function pointer
to assign.

I've been trying for hours now to define a function pointer passed a function with variadic arguments
can be.

Here is my code with the corresponding error message, marked with ===========

How must the pointer and the two functions be defined.
Many thanks for the help

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <esp32-hal-uart.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

/* ---------------------------------------------------------
 * Defines
 --------------------------------------------------------- */

#if ARDUHAL_LOG_LEVEL >= ARDUHAL_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG
#ifndef USE_ESP_IDF_LOG
#define logx(format, ...) logStruct.loggerCb(ARDUHAL_LOG_FORMAT(X, format), ##__VA_ARGS__)
#endif  //................^ 'logStruct' was not declared in this scope ======================
#endif

/* ---------------------------------------------------------
 * Type Definitions
 --------------------------------------------------------- */

template <typename... Args>
using logging_t = void(const char *, Args &&...args);

template <typename... Args>
struct LogStruct_t {
    logging_t<Args> *loggerCb;
};  //...............^parameter packs not expanded with '...': ======================

/* ---------------------------------------------------------
 * Static Function / Prototypes
 --------------------------------------------------------- */

template <typename... Args>
LogStruct_t<Args> logStruct;
// .........^ parameter pack "Args" was referenced but not expanded  ======================
// ...............^ "logStruct" is not a function or static data member  ======================

template <typename... Args>
static void nativeLogger(const char *format, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    vfprintf(stderr, format, args);
    va_end(args);
}

template <typename... Args>
static void arduinoLogger(const char *format, Args &&...args) {
    log_printf(format, args...);
}

void setup() {
    // put either nativeLogger or arduinoLogger
    logStruct.loggerCb = nativeLogger;
    //..^ identifier "logStruct" is undefined  ======================
    logStruct.loggerCb = arduinoLogger;
    //
    int a = 2;
    logx("Text val1: %d, val2: %u", a, 123);
    //.^ identifier "ARDUHAL_LOG_COLOR_X" is undefined  ======================
}

void loop() {
    // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}

/*===================================================================================
Output

=====================================================================================
*/
```

Comment: `nativeLogger`'s definition doesn't make sense. Either it is a C-style variadic function, in which case it shouldn't be a template or it is a C++-style variadic function template, in which case it should be declared like `arduinoLogger`. You can't have a function pointer point to a templated function like `arduinoLogger` either. What is the signature of `log_printf`? Does it need the arguments to be typed or is it also a C-style variadic function?

Comment: `LogStruct_t` is an infinite family of types; `logStruct` is an infinite family of variables. You wish to pretend that there's just one global variable `logStruct` that's magically of just the right type for the arguments being logged, but that ain't how it works. There's no variable named `logStruct` - there's a variable named, say, `logStruct<int, unsigned>`, and another unrelated variable named say `logStruct<const char*, int, long>`

Comment: Do you need to switch between the two loggers at run time, or at compile time? If at compile time, just define your `logx` macro to expand to a `nativeLogger` call or `arduinoLogger` call based on a compile-time setting. If at run time, define a wrapper function template that would turn around and call one or the other based on the runtime check. This function pointer idea ain't gonna fly - you can't have a pointer to a function template, only to a specific instantiation of that template.

Comment: @user17732522 The signatur is:
`int log_printf(const char *format, ...)`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Tandetnik I would switch the loggers at compile time. I will try to implement your suggested solution. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @eismeraldo Then you don't need any templates. The pointer can simply be of type `void(*)(const char*, ...)` and you can implement `arduinoLogger` like `nativeLogger`, but in both cases without the `template` head. But if this is supposed to be a compile-time decision, then Igor's recommendation is a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is now solved using macros as suggested by IgorTandetnik Tandetnik. Thank you again.
Here some code snippets:

```
#ifdef ARDUINO_ESP32_DEV  // Compile flags are displayed by: “Advanced → Verbose Build”

#include <Arduino.h>
#include <esp32-hal-uart.h>

template <typename... Args>
int arduinoLogger(const char* format, Args&&... args) {
    return log_printf(format, args...);
}

#if ARDUHAL_LOG_LEVEL >= ARDUHAL_LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE
#define logv(format, ...) arduinoLogger(ARDUHAL_LOG_FORMAT(V, format), ##__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define logv(format, ...) \
    do {                  \
    } while (0)
#endif


#else
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// used by hal log
const char* pathToFileName(const char* path) {
    size_t i = 0;
    size_t pos = 0;
    char* p = (char*)path;
    while (*p) {
        i++;
        if (*p == '/' || *p == '\\') {
            pos = i;
        }
        p++;
    }
    return path + pos;
}

void nativeLogger(const char* format, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    vfprintf(stderr, format, args);
    va_end(args);
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#define NATIVEHAL_LOG_FORMAT(letter, format) \
    "[%s][%s:%u] %s(): \r\n", letter, pathToFileName(__FILE__), __LINE__, __FUNCTION__

#if ARDUHAL_LOG_LEVEL >= ARDUHAL_LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE
#define logv(format, ...) nativeLogger(NATIVEHAL_LOG_FORMAT("V", format), ##__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define logv(format, ...) \
    do {                  \
    } while (0)
#endif
#endif
```